# Incrementing specific parameter in all objects in the QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to increment the same parameter in all objects in the query set.

What I am doing right now:

```
q = SomeModel.objects.all()
for object in q:
   object.my_parameter += 1
   object.save()
```

I have wondered if it could be achieved in a simpler way, e.g. using update() function. To put it simply I would like to do something like this:

```
SomeModel.objects.all().update(my_parameter += 1)
```

I just can't believe that there is no shortcut for what I want to do.

Edit:
Resolved! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by F() expressions

```
from django.db.models import F

SomeModel.objects.all().update(my_parameter=F('my_parameter') + 1)
```

Further reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Answer (score -1):

Certainly you could do it in a single bulk update. Check this out: [Updating multiple objects at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once). 
I prefer to use the [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F)  too:

```
from django.db.models import F
SomeModel.objects.all().update(my_parameter =F('my_parameter') + 1)
```

Comment: this is the exact same answer , could have suggested an edit